# How can I add a namespace when I use XPath using $x function in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, xpath

I usually use [$x()](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#xpath-function) function on Google Chrome development console. However, when XML file has a namespace the query does not work. I could not find any way to add the namespace.  I was wondering if I am missing something or is a missing feature.

Comment: Just to be sure, I assume you meant XPath, not XQuery?

Comment: I would look at the source code of the implementation of `$x` in Chromium to find out whether it supports any namespace resolution; unfortunately I don't know my way around that code base to quickly identify the function, for Firefox I found it in https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/server/actors/webconsole/utils.js#327 and it clearly passes `null` to `document.evaluate`, meaning in case of Firefox there is *no* support for namespace resolution and `$x` in the developer tools console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is a way to include namespaces in the function, but it's possible to (try to) avoid them altogether by using `local-name()`.

For example, if your element is (picked randomly for an EDGAR filing):

```
<edgar:companyName>Federal Bank of Boston</edgar:companyName>
```

This expression

```
$x('//*[local-name()="companyName"]')
```

should select it.

Comment: thanks that works for simple queries. I am trying to get rid of the namespace from the xml but it seems I can't, so I think I'll use your solution.

Comment: @GM - It actually works for very complex queries on deeply nested xml; the problem is that it becomes pretty difficult to parse since you have to repeat the `*[local-name()="xyz"]` sequence for every element in the xpath statement (and sometimes for attribute names as well...). But it does work.

Comment: If Chrome supports XPath, I'd expect the wildcard name test to work: `$x('//*:companyName')`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#node-tests.

Comment: @JoeWicentowski One would hope so, but no: Chrome (and Firefox) does support xpath, but only xpath 1.0; Your expression (and the page you link to) only works for xpath 3.1.  People have been complaining about lack of browser xpath 3.1 support for years and years, to no avail...